# For two overlapping lines, choose one with better attributes python

Tags: python

I have a set of lines that consist of N points each. Each line has a "goodness attribute" for example:

- line.points: [p1,p2,p3,....,pN]
- line.goodness: 1.5

However, multiple lines can overlap in up to N-1 points. If this is the case, I want to choose the line with the higher line.goodness.
The algorithm should look something like (open to suggestions here):

- group together all lines that overlap in N-1 points. This will lead to clusters of overlapping lines.
- From each cluster, remove all lines from original set besides the one with the highest goodness.
- Group together all lines that overlap in N-2 points. Again, reduce original set by only keeping the ones that have highest goodness.
- do this until no lines overlap anymore/N=0

I implemented this like:

```
def point_overlap(line1, line2, N_overlaps):
    result=False
    buf=0
    for line1_point in line1.points:
        for line2_point in line2.points:
            if line1_point==line2_point:
                 buf+=1
    if buf==N_overlaps: 
       result=True
    return result

def choose_worse_line(line1,line2): 
    if line1.goodness<=line2.goodness:
       return line1
    return line2

len_lines=100
for N in reversed(range(len_lines)):
    lines_that_overlap=[[line1,line2] for line1 in line_set for line2 in line_set if point_overlap(line1, line2, N)==True]
    if not lines_set:
        break
    worse_line=[choose_worse_line(line[0],line[1]) for line in lines_that_overlap]
    lines_set=[line for line in line_set if line not in worse_line]
```

This is very, very slow and also feels very clumsy to me. Does anyone know of a more efficient, cleverer solution?

Comment: Could you provide a data set for benchmark?

Comment: I think it'd also help knowing how your `Line` and `Point` class (I assume they're classes) look like. Also: if two lines have the same highest goodness, do you keep one or do you have to keep both?